# Get value from ID of AJAX-loaded content

Tags: javascript, php

I have javascript to get content from another page, like this :

```
$.get('disp/run_txt.php?type=andon&dispnm=PS&line=1',function(data){
    $('#result').html(data);
  });
```

What I want is the value of id='result' can transfer to variable, i have try :

```php
$result = "<span id='runtxt'></span>";
echo $result;
```

My question is, how to capture the `id='result'` to variable?

Comment: Are you trying to capture `id="example"` or `example`?

Comment: which id ? youre question is unclear

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var resultVariable = $('#result').val(); //For non-text value
```

OR

```
var resultVariable = $('#result').text(); //For text value
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass what you have in data to some PHP code, you will have to do an ajax call to a php page.

```
$.get('disp/run_txt.php?type=andon&dispnm=PS&line=1',function(data){

    $('#result').html(data);

    var url = 'your-php-page.php';

    // Will now send data to your-php-page.php
    // where you can assign it to the variable
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: success,
        dataType: dataType
    });

});
```